# Best practices for using Cloud Firestore and Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, state

More specifically I'm asking about best practices for state management and reading and writing to firestore. I started to wonder about this after starting to set up and layout my data model for a website I'm working on in. My current understanding of firestore is that the most basic ways to get data from a collection or document is using the get() method to receive a one time read, or using onSnapshot() to receive a a real-time data stream of the document. Because of these different methods, it got me thinking about the best way to set up my component and state logic.

1. You could initially call the get() method and set it equal to component state. You could then use that state to pass data to the component and children. To write/and remove data you could concurrently write/remove both to the state and to the firestore document. This seems to have the benefit of limited reads, but more writes. It also seems to add to the possibility of desync between the component state and the actual document.
2. To reduce the amount of writes, could it be possible to continue the write/remove to the state, but not the firestore document concurrently? Instead, could you use a useEffect return function to write/remove the difference between the state and the document once the component unmounts? This option seems to have limited reads, limited writes, and having a single source of truth for the data (the state). But, the logic for the unmount document write could be more complicated.
3. It also seems possible to use the onSnapshot() method to remove the concurrent writes/remove on the state, and have them solely on the document. It seems to be possible to listen to the changes to the document and update the state from that document directly each time. This option seems to have the benefits of easy state logic and no desync between the state and the documents. But in turns it seems like this would cause a lot of reads and writes.

I haven't found too much information discussing these ideas directly, and I was curious on what were the current best practices in dealing with data flow and state management related to the above examples. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: While this is a start to a good question it's very broad and would take a lot of discussion to really understand what you're after or what the issue is. Those kinds of questions are generally not well suited for SO (this is a coding forum, write some code and when you get stuck, post it.). Firebase is an event driven database - you can get data once, or get data once and then be notified of future changes through those events. So may I ask what is the actual problem you're facing? Do you have a section of code that's not working?

Comment: Right now it's just how to set up the layout of one of my components that the user interacts with a lot but all the data is stored on Firestore. I was planning on writing a bit of code for each example. Seeing if I did something inefficiently or unintended might be a better way of addressing this problem.

Answer (score 4):

### creating the [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) for the app

first we'll create a context for the firestore access and wrap the App with its provider lets call it `AuthProvider` and we'll create a hook `useAuth` to access necessary methods or accessing firestore-db

let's start with creating the context as -

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import React from "react";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

let AuthContext = React.createContext(null);

function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  let [initializing, setInitializing] = React.useState(true);
  let [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

  let authChanged = React.useCallback((firebaseUser) => {
    if (firebaseUser) setUser(firebaseUser);
    setInitializing(false);

    console.log({ firebaseUser });
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, authChanged);
    return subscriber;
  }, [authChanged]);

  let signin = async (newUser, successCallback, errorCallback) => {
    setInitializing(true);
    try {
      let res = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        newUser.email,
        newUser.password
      );
      if (res.user) return successCallback();

      return errorCallback("Wrong credentials");
    } catch (error) {
      return errorCallback("Something went Wrong.");
    }
  };

  let signout = async (callback) => {
    await signOut(auth);
    setUser(null);
    callback();
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ initializing, user, signin, signout, db }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default AuthProvider;
export { AuthContext };
```

now for the hook we'll simply do -

```js
import React from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./authProvider";

function useAuth() {
  return React.useContext(AuthContext);
}

export default useAuth;
```

now that we've created the hook we are ready for the next step

NOTE: make use of `signin` in your login screen for strict access, and `signout`

### getting along with [`react-router-dom`](https://reactrouter.com/)

wrap all your routes that needs acces to **firestore** data with below component (p.s use `react-router-dom` for route)

```js
export function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  let auth = useAuth();   // we'll create this hook to manage firbase auth and database access
  let location = useLocation(); // hook from react-router-dom

  if (auth.initializing) return null;

  if (!auth.user)
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;

  return children;
}
```

now we'll access firestore from our hook on components(routes) as

```js
export default function Documents() {
  const [docs, setDocs] = React.useState([]);
  const [docsLoading, setDocsLoading] = React.useState(true);

  let { user, db } = useAuth();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function getUserDocuments() {
      setDocsLoading(true);
      const q = query(collection(db, "docs"), where("author", "==", user.uid));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      const tmpDocs = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        tmpDocs.push({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() });
      });
      setDocs(tmpDocs);
      setDocsLoading(false);
    }

    getUserDocuments();
  }, []);

  return !docsLoading ? (
        docs.map((doc) => (/* show in ui */))
   ) : (
      <div>some loader... until we are loading data</div>
   )
)
```

I'll be more than happy to address your doubts in comments :)

Comment: I appreciate the in-depth write up! It's always good to see how different people approach the authentication flow. I have a similar set up, but I'm also using next.js so the routing and authenticationCheck/protected pages are  a bit different. You're example of reading Firestone is solid and I have a similar flow but I guess my original question was more based towards how to deal with read write loop while using Firestore and user interaction with the document.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, was wrestling with the best way to manage server-side state from Firestore in a react web app -- especially in light of the announcement about [Concurrent React](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#what-is-concurrent-react).

I ended up writing my own state-management library.

You might want to check out [@gmcfall/react-firebase-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gmcfall/react-firebase-state)
.  It uses listeners to ensure that data is fresh, and it is resilient in the face of many render cycles and multiple mount/unmount cycles.

You wrote that

> .. it seems like (onSnapshot) would cause a lot of reads and writes.

My experience is just the opposite. I have to make fewer trips to the server to ensure that my data is fresh. The key to this solution is to have components "lease" data from a local cache that holds server-side state. But entities don't get evicted from the cache immediately when the number of claims on the data goes to zero.  This way, if the user navigates away from the component briefly  and then returns, or if concurrent rendering kicks in, the data will still be there, and it is guaranteed to be up-to-date.